# Conditionally select dataframes from a list of dfs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to subset a list of dataframes with a function. This function would need to return only the df's which for example have a Z-column-total of > 14 and X-column-values (rows 0-4) which are 30% below or above the average of those 5 values. So, in the example below df1 would be returned and df2 not.

Can this be done, evaluating every dataframe with these kinds of conditions? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
N = 5                                                                                                                                    
np.random.seed(0)                                                                                                                                                    

df1 = pd.DataFrame(                                                                                                                                                  
         {'X':np.random.uniform(0,5,N),                                                                                                                               
          'Y':np.random.uniform(0,5,N),                                                                                                                               
          'Z':np.random.uniform(0,5,N),                                                                                                                               
               })                                                                                                                                                     
df2 = pd.DataFrame(                                                                                                                                                  
          {'X':np.random.uniform(0,5,N),                                                                                                                               
          'Y':np.random.uniform(0,5,N),                                                                                                                               
           'Z':np.random.uniform(0,5,N),                                                                                                                               
                })                                                                                                                                                     

df1.loc['total'] = df1.sum()                                                                                                                                         
df2.loc['total'] = df2.sum()                                                                                                                                         

df_list = (df1, df2)

               X          Y          Z
0       2.744068   3.229471   3.958625
1       3.575947   2.187936   2.644475
2       3.013817   4.458865   2.840223
3       2.724416   4.818314   4.627983
4       2.118274   1.917208   0.355180
total  14.176521  16.611793  14.426486
--------------------------------------
               X          Y          Z
0       0.435646   4.893092   3.199605
1       0.101092   3.995793   0.716766
2       4.163099   2.307397   4.723345
3       3.890784   3.902646   2.609242
4       4.350061   0.591372   2.073310
total  12.940682  15.690299  13.322267
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of dataframes then conditionally select the dataframe using list comprehension and you can use slicing (`iloc[0:-1]` for excluding last row).

```
new_list= [x for x in df_list if (x.loc['total','Z']>14) and 
      ((x.iloc[0:-1]['X'] > x.iloc[0:-1]['X'].mean()*0.7) & (x.iloc[0:-1]['X'] < x.iloc[0:-1]['X'].mean()*1.3)).all()]
```

Output:

```
[               X          Y          Z
 0       2.744068   3.229471   3.958625
 1       3.575947   2.187936   2.644475
 2       3.013817   4.458865   2.840223
 3       2.724416   4.818314   4.627983
 4       2.118274   1.917208   0.355180
 total  14.176521  16.611793  14.426486]
```

Comment: thanks, and how about the other condition? the averages of the x-values?

Comment: One thing, I need the complete df, not only the rows

Comment: "30% of the average of those 5 values" not 30% of the total value

Comment: "30% of the average of those 5 values", that's in Bharath's solution missing as well. The average is 2.834, every X-value needs to be within 30% of that, so between 1.984 and 3.684.

Comment: I updated the answer and I still don't get how withing 30% mean between 1.984 and 3.684.

Comment: 0.7 * 2.834 = 1.984 and 1.3 * 2.834 = 3.684, so in fact a bandwith to which the values are compared.

Comment: Ohk you meant below and above 30% of the average. Then the total will always be above 1.3. and here we end up in empty list

Comment: Updated my answer by excluding last row. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, That's it, thanks. I've accepted your answer. I like this being a one - liner

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension can be used, with the 2 stated conditions.

The Z condition is pretty straightforward and easy to implement. Regarding the X condition, I created a little function that returns True if the dataframe matches the condition, else False.

```
In [156]: def check_X(df):
     ...:     avg = df.drop('total')['X'].mean()
     ...:     for val in df.drop('total')['X']:
     ...:         if val/avg < 0.7 or val/avg > 1.3:  #30% more or less
     ...:             return False
     ...:     return True
     ...:
```

Therefore, we can get the expected result by doing:

```
In [157]: [df for df in df_list if df.drop('total')['Z'].sum() > 14 and check_X(df)]
Out[157]: 
[               X          Y          Z
 0       2.744068   3.229471   3.958625
 1       3.575947   2.187936   2.644475
 2       3.013817   4.458865   2.840223
 3       2.724416   4.818314   4.627983
 4       2.118274   1.917208   0.355180
 total  14.176522  16.611794  14.426486]
```

*Edit:* a better, one-liner solution that doesn't use any user-defined function:

```
In [205]: [df for df in df_list if df['Z'].sum() > 14 and ((df['X'] > df['X'].mean()*0.7) & (df['X'] < df['X'].mean()*1.3)).all()]
Out[205]: 
[          X         Y         Z
 0  2.744068  3.229471  3.958625
 1  3.575947  2.187936  2.644475
 2  3.013817  4.458865  2.840223
 3  2.724416  4.818314  4.627983
 4  2.118274  1.917208  0.355180]
```

For simplicity, I dropped the 'total' row from both df before processing:

```
In [204]: df_list = [df.drop('total') for df in df_list]
```

Comment: great, only I need the 'total' - row as well

Comment: @Zanshin why don't you compute it afterward ?

Comment: I tried, get an empty result now. Btw you perform a calculation on the Z-column before evaluating in the list comprehension. I'd prefer the value as is, I think. So what Bharath has in his solution.

Comment: My point is, rather than computing the total and putting in the dataframe (which hinders column-based computation), you should just compute it whenever needed later on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the answer from Bharath works best for me in addition to being a one liner. I will be able to use your input as well, thanks